# Pass value and get value in jquery between two pages

Tags: jquery, get

I'm really struck here. I have a form  and i want to submit it and get value on other page in Jquery:

```
<form id="rentals_form" name="popup_form" action="rentals.php" method="POST">
<input alt="" style="display:none;" id="copy_id" name="copy_id" type="text">
</form>

<button 
class="save_button" 
value="copy_listing_button" 
onclick="document.forms[$('#copy_listing option:selected').val()+'_form'].submit();" 
style="font-size:11px; padding:0 3px 0 3px;">
    Go
</button>
```

Now i want to get copy_id value in rentals.php with jquery not php

```
 $(document).ready(function() 
 {
// here I want to get copy_id value.please note this is jquery so i want to get in jquery
 });
```

Comment: when you execute form,you actually send values to other page with php as they are at server. You can set value in js also if page is php with: var result = <?php echo $_POST['copy_id']; ?> i guess ...

Comment: What if i pass it in action?can i do that?

Comment: you mean action = "rendals.php?value=x"? than that is get method,but as you already send form that is bad. But even then it is using php to send data. yes,you can set cookie also as ganeshrj said if you really want to avoid php at all, but i dont see why. On sidenote, a lot of users disable cookies.

Comment: yes i want to use action = "rendals.php?value=x",but how i can use jquery variable instead of x(to get value of copy_id)?and then i will get there on other page

Comment: first dont use ?var in form, you already send form using POST method. Either use as i wrote on other page js code (js is javascript, jQuery is 100% javascript and this problem has nothing to do with jQuery):  var result = <?php echo $_POST['copy_id']; ?>; and then you use result variable wherever you want or read about cookies what one guy posted here as answer.

Comment: for sending value,i recommend using hidden field like: <input id="copy_id" name="copy_id" type="hidden" value="your_value">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Set cookie using js in the first page . Refer [cookie](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)
   to create cookie in js

2.get that cookie in other page.

Answer (score 0):

These lines in rentals.php will do the trick :

```
<!-- This should be somewhere in the <head> but before your main script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var copy_id_value = <?=$_POST['copy_id']?>;
</script>
```